# I am receiving this error? Error : (1226) User 'qe' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 30)

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, server

So, after researching about this alot i am seeking help for somebody who encountered this and got a way out.

We developed a PTC script for a client and it worked fine, but as the users grew it starting displaying an error which is as below:

**Error : (1226) User 'qe' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 30)**

Now after seeking help somebody said its a server related issue and other people pointed that it was an issue related to the database design of the script.

Looking forward for a way to solve this problem. Have tried tons of things.

Using godaddy hosting at the moment, they increased the Limit from 30 to 50, but im sure the problem is going to show up again.

Comment: You need to provide some additional detail about the software and how that error was generated. You should also describe what you have tried, what db you are using (MySQL? PostgreSQL? Oracle? MSSQL?)

It does definitely sound like a db issue.

Comment: We are using Mysqli, PHP written script. The error appears when the number of users exceed on the website. The users come to the website to click ads.

Comment: It could be your script not closing the connection properly. How many concurrent connections do you generally have on the site?

Comment: Where is your php code? I cannot see it in the question.

Comment: And where are the "tons of things" you tried? Can't see a trace of them either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no problem with the database, the problem is in how you handle database connections from your software.

The way your script is set up is that every connection to your web server also opens a connection towards MySQL. That's not the scenario you want.

Raising the limit won't fix the issue, it will just delay yet another error. What you should do is use persistent connections.

One of the reasons why using `php-fpm` instead of server API's such as `mod_php` is preferred is because a set number of PHP processes is booted and a pool of connections to services is created.

The flow would be the following:

- use `php-fpm`. `Apache` and `nginx` can use FCGI interface to speak to `php-fpm` processes
- raise a relatively low amount of child processes for `php-fpm`. This shouldn't be overly large, default config usually works out, I'll make a guess that you don't run a hexacore system so 4-6 child processes should be fine
- use persistent MySQL connections

What does this do? Your server accepts the request and sends it to `php-fpm`, which processes it when it becomes free. Each process uses 1 connection to MySQL. This means you can never hit some sort of hard limit like you have.

If your server is busy, the server should queue up the requests until PHP is capable of handling them. Be it `Apache` or `nginx` that you use, this approach will work well.

If your site is busy, it's likely that web server is working faster to accept connections and serve static content that PHP is to process dynamic content. In this case you have an option of adding another physical machine (or more) that runs `php-fpm`. Instructing your web server to round-robin between machines that serve PHP is trivial, for both of mentioned web servers.

Bottom line is that you want to utilize your resources in an optimal way. Opening and closing MySQL connections on every request isn't optimal. Pooling connections is.

Comment: Comment assumes db server has reasonable setting for max_connections and also assumes things about code without any code having been posted. Poster tries to foist entirely separate technology on obvious noob user.

Comment: @N.B. Your answer has opened a new dimension in which i wasn't even thinking. (S.Imp) Previously i had been changing and optimizing my database tables using different techniques, which obviously wasn't solving my problem. The problem as highlighted by (N.B.) makes total sense as i haven't worked on anything related to opening and closing the connection from the user to the database. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @N.B. The tenor of the OP suggests that they struggle with basic concepts. Encouraging them to alter basic php/web server installation seems totally unreasonable -- and your suggestions offer no details about how they might "use php-fpm". You offer no links or documentation or instructions or anything. If you're going to be pedantic, at least be thorough.

Comment: Suppose, for the sake of argument, the user has non-fpm PHP web server but is connected to an entirely separate and very powerful MySQL instance with tons of RAM. The server, despite all its RAM, has not been configured with a suitable max_connections value. Wouldn't it be easier to increase this value than reinstall/recompile/reconfigure Apache or PHP? Or in certain PHP apps, turning off persistent connections solves this problem. Your solution may in fact work, but assumed a LOT about their code and setup, which is not very thoughtful. Also, I voted it down because I'm after the critic badge